# set -e and background process

Tags: bash, shell

In my script I set `set -e` to stop processing if an error occurs. It works well for all commands running in foreground, but some of my commands must be run in parallel in background. 
Unfortunately if background process fails the script is not stopped although `set -e` flag.

Example with foreground process works.

```
#!/bin/bash
set -e
ls -l no_file
sleep 100
```

Example with background process does not work.

```
#!/bin/bash
set -e
ls -l no_file &
sleep 100
```

How to handle failures of the background processes?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Starting a command asychronously (with `&`) always returns exit status 0. To get the actual exit status of the command use the builtin `wait`. A simple example:

```
$ (sleep 5; ls -l nofile) &
[1] 3831
$ echo $?
0
$ wait -n
ls: cannot access 'nofile': No such file or directory
[1]+  Exit 2                  ( sleep 5; ls --color=auto -l nofile )
$ echo $?
2
```

`wait -n` waits for *any* child process (which can be very useful). If you want to wait for a specific process, you can capture the PID when you start it -- it's in the special variable `$!` -- then wait by PID:

```
$ (sleep 5; ls -l nofile) &
$ myjobpid=$!
$ # do some other stuff in parallel
$ wait ${myjobpid}
ls: cannot access 'nofile': No such file or directory
[1]+  Exit 2                  ( sleep 5; ls --color=auto -l nofile )
```

The relevant section of the Bash manual is titled "Job control"

Comment: Solution with wait for PID is perfectly what I'm looking for. Thanks.

Comment: I don't see this answering how this interacts with `set -e` which is the original question.

Comment: @user239558: First sentence in this answer: *"Starting a command asychronously (with &) always returns exit status 0"*. That is, it is always successful, as in, not an error. The actual question is the last sentence in the original post: *"How to handle failures of the background processes?"*

Comment: I think the answer should clarify 3 things:  the difference between `wait` and `wait -n`, the effect of calling `wait` or `wait -n` when no background process exist, and a pattern for handling background processes.